# Why at the beginning of the project build with an error on NODE_PATH Win 7/8?

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, reactjs, gulp

I try to run this project https://github.com/alexfedoseev/universal-basics, but there are the following errors  (npm run start):

- NODE_PATH
- Command failed (when copying)

Screenshot [image]

I know that everything is OK on Mac, errors appear only on Windows 7/8.
I think the problem is in the file I think the problem is in the file gulpfile.babel.js.

Comment: Did you add the node executable to your PATH?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the question. Please clarify.
I haven't changed anything. And this problem in two different systems.